# Asp.Net Core 2.1 Identity - UserStore dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to implement a custom `UserStore` for my identity models; however, I'm getting this run-time error on app startup:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   '[Project].Models.Identity.ApplicationUserStore' while attempting to
>   activate '[Project].Models.Identity.ApplicationUserManager'.

Stack:

> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type
>   serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain,
>   ParameterInfo[] parameters, bool throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Type
>   serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor
>   descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type
>   serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type
>   serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor(Type
>   serviceType) System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func valueFactory)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass22_0.b__0(IServiceProvider services)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
>   factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
>   scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
>   scope)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
>   sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
>   lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref
>   State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref
>   State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

My `UserStore` implementation:

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : IUserStore<Employee>,
                     IUserClaimStore<Employee>,
                     IUserLoginStore<Employee>,
                     IUserRoleStore<Employee>,
                     IUserPasswordStore<Employee>,
                     IUserSecurityStampStore<Employee>
{
    #region Constructor signatures I tried for dependency injection
    public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null)
    {

    }
    public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {

    }
    public ApplicationUserStore()
    {

    }
    public ApplicationUserStore(DbContext context)
    {

    }
    #endregion
    ...
```

My `UserManager` implementation:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<Employee>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationUserStore store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<Employee> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<Employee>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<Employee>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<Employee>> logger)
        : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {
    }
}
```

My `SignInManager` implementation:

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<Employee>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<Employee> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, ILogger<SignInManager<Employee>> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
        : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes)
    {
    }
}
```

And, in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
        ...
        services.AddIdentityCore<Employee>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
            .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
            .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddTransient<IUserStore<Employee>, ApplicationUserStore>();
        ...
```

I need to know what causes the problem, how to solve it, and whether there's a documentation anywhere for Asp.Net Core 2.1 dependency injection activator signatures.

Comment: if you declare services.AddTransient<IUserStore<Employee>, ApplicationUserStore>(), you cannot use ApplicationUserStore in your contructors.  You need to use IUserStore<Employee>

Comment: @hugo. Unfortunately, using `AddTransient` without `AddUserStore` didn't work with me, neither did using `AddUserStore` without `AddTransient`; I keep receiving the same message.

Comment: Have you registered `ApplicationDbContext`?

Comment: @Brad. I guess it's being registered by this line `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()`.

Comment: It isn't.  That line is simply telling Identity the type of IdentityDbContext to use.  It expects it to be pre-configured and registered e.g. `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();`.  You may have similar problems with your other custom services.

Comment: @Brad. That was really close; instead of that, I had to register `UserStore` through `AddScoped` - I came up with the solution; if interested, please see the answer.

Comment: Down-voter, would you state why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reviewing open-source implementation [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Core/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs), and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs), I came up with a clue to what the issue might have been - and I guessed right. The `UserStore` needed to be registered through this line in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
    services.AddScoped<ApplicationUserStore>();
```

So, my final approach was:

```
    ...
    services.AddIdentityCore<Employee>()
        .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
        .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddScoped<IUserStore<Employee>, ApplicationUserStore>();
    services.AddScoped<ApplicationUserStore>();
    ...
```

Even though, it worked without:

```
    services.AddScoped<IUserStore<Employee>, ApplicationUserStore>();
```

Comment: Thanks! I was having a similar issue with the DbContext dependency injection. (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService) and the issue was resolved by entering another services.AddDbContext item in the Startup.cs file.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. What exactly is the ApplicationUserStrore? I was not able to find ApplicationUserStore within the links provided

Comment: @T3.0 `ApplicationUserStore`, as provided in the question, is the custom `IUserStore` for my custom user type.

Comment: Thanks. I added an isEnabled property to my custom usertype and I have not created a custom userstore. Perhaps that is the cause of my error. `Unable to resolve service for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore 1[Myapp.Areas.Identity.Data.xyzUser] while attempting to activate Myapp.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage.CustomUserEditPage.////// at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
 at lambda_method...`

Comment: thanks for this, this really got me out of dependency injection h*ll!